# Select Element in a Namespace with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

I want to select the topmost element in a document that has a given namespace (prefix).

More specifically: I have XML documents that either start with /html/body (in the XHTML namespace) or with one of several elements in a particular namespace. I effectively want to strip out /html/body and just return the body contents OR the entire root namespaced element.

Comment: In the course of writing up my post, I stumbled into a working solution, so I community-owned the question and then posted the answer. Enjoy!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In XPath 2.0 and XQuery 1.0 you can test against the namespace prefix using the [in-scope-prefixes()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-in-scope-prefixes) function in a predicate. 
e.g.

```
//*[in-scope-prefixes(.)='html']
```

If you cant use v2, in XPath 1.0 you can use the [namespace-uri()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-namespace-uri) function to test against the namespace itself.
e.g.

```
//*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml']
```

Answer (score 3):

The XPath expression that I want is:

```
/html:html/html:body/node()|/foo:*
```

Where the "html" prefix is mapped to the XHTML namespace, and the "foo" prefix is mapped to my target namespace.