# Soap response message parsing using XPath

Tags: java, xpath

I try to parse soap response using `xpath` , below the some code of response message.

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns1:Get__CompIntfc__CI_PERSONAL_DATAResponse
xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas/M985361.V1">
<ns1:PROP_EMPLID>AA0001</ns1:PROP_EMPLID>
<ns1:PROP_LAST_NAME>Adams</ns1:PROP_LAST_NAME><ns1:PROP_FIRST_NAME>Kimberly</ns1:PROP_FIRST_NAME>
</ns1:Get__CompIntfc__CI_PERSONAL_DATAResponse >
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I try to parse it like...

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
     DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
     ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
     response.writeTo(out); 
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( out.toByteArray() ); 
Document doc = builder.parse( is );
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//ns1:PROP_EMPLID/text()");
           Object res = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
           NodeList nodes = (NodeList) res;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
       }
```

It not give the required value "AA0001" 
but when i use `xpath.compile("//*/text()")`  it prints all text node value properly.

Please tell me what is the problem because I want some specific values from response not all text values.

Comment: You write wrong name of Node (you include namespace in it).
Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112601/select-element-in-a-namespace-with-xpath

Comment: you may can find answer here: [finding tags in soap xml directly by name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65397403/8496599)

Comment: You may find answer hehe: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65397403/8496599)

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to retrieve a node in the namespace represented by the prefix `ns1`, but your application has *no idea* what this prefix represents, because you haven't associated this name with any actual namespace. The way to do this in Java (as mentioned by @newtover) is to register an instance of a `javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext` with your `xpath` object. Something like this:

```
xpath.setNamespaceContext(namespaces);
```

Unfortunately, there is **no default implementation** of this interface. You'll need to roll your own. A complete example can be found here:

- [How to query XML using namespaces in Java with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390339/how-to-query-xml-using-namespaces-in-java-with-xpath/6392700#6392700)

...or by following @newtover's link.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a [NamespaceContext](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/#listing6) to your xpath expression.